# Simulating p2p model in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, p2p

I want to use a problem with P2P method in Netlogo.

I modified Uri Wilensky Traffic Grid model. Every light has its knowledge about number of its car (who are waiting at light).

I want to count all number of car without global number, just asking light by light (between neighbors)

Somebody can help me? How can I count all agent or patch without global variable or functions with peer-to-peer?

Comment: I am afraid I don't get your problem entirely. How did you model the knowledge of the traffic lights? Do you want a simple total of all waiting cars? I'd suggest to edit your question and include some code. I think that would make it clearer.